# Invalid number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021)

Tags: batch-file

I wish to execute a batch file and have it call itself 10 times.

```
set /a iteration=0%1+1
IF %iteration% EQU 10 exit
rem Taskkill /IM aspnet_compiler.exe /F
timeout 1
call KillBILLd.bat %iteration%
```

However, it will only get to the number 8 before erroring with

```
Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), 
or octal (021).
```

on line

```
set /a iteration=0%1+1
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got `0%1` in that expression - if your argument is 8, that expands to `08`, which isn't a valid octal number (8 is not an octal digit), and so you get that error.  I'm not a batch file expert, but I guess you want to leave off the leading `0`:

```
set /a iteration=%1+1
```

Here's a link to some [SET command documentation](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php).

Comment: Ohhh! I was trying to cheat because the first time i call the batch file, no number is being passed in. I fixed this with an if statement setting iteration to zero if %1 is empty.

Comment: But it's not necessary to test if `%1` is empty, as your expression is also valid with an empty `%1`

Answer (score 4):

As Carl said, the leading zero is the sign for octal numbers.
Sometimes a leading zero seems to be useful, as you would avoid an error in case `%1` is empty.

But then you got this type of problems, which can be solved by using a little bit other way.

Prepending a `1` or better `100` and then building the modulo will also work with the numbers 8 and 9 (and also empty input).

```
set /a iteration=1000%1 %% 100 + 1
```

But in your case it removing the zero should be enough, even if `%1` is empty you got a valid expression.

```
set /a iteration=%1 + 1
```

Would expand to `set /a iteration= + 1`