# Batch error: Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021)

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm extracting two digits and adding one to it. But when the last two digits are 08 it's throwing the above error.

```
set last_two=!file_name:~-2,2!
set /a add_millisec=!last_two!+1
set add_millisec=0!add_millisec!
set add_millisec=!add_millisec:~-2!
```

Can someone please check and help me here...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762794/invalid-number-numeric-constants-are-either-decimal-17-hexadecimal-0x11-o)

Comment: constants begin with 0 are octal values, but 8 and 9 is not a valid octal digit, therefore you got the error

Comment: Yes, since 8 and 9 are not octal digits I'm getting that error.. is there any way I can avoid this and continue with my flow

Comment: There are several ways you can find in the other question. The easiest one being appending 1 to the beginning and then subtract 100

Comment: thank you, it worked.. I've appended 1 in front of it

Comment: Avoid the pain and use PowerShell instead of batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a command prompt window and type `set /?`:

> [...]  Numeric values are decimal numbers, unless prefixed by 0x for hexadecimal numbers, and 0 for octal numbers. So 0x12 is the same as 18 is the same as 022. Please note that the octal notation can be confusing: 08 and 09 are not valid numbers because 8 and 9 are not valid octal digits.  [...]

You will find that `set /A` treats numbers with leading `0` as octal numbers.

To overcome this, you can do the following:

1. Prefix the number with `1` and remove it again after the calculations:

   ```
   set last_two=1!file_name:~-2,2!
   set /A add_millisec=last_two+1
   set add_millisec=!add_millisec:~-2!
   ```

   For this you need to know the total number of digits in advance.
2. Remove the trailing zeros before any calculations and pad the result with leading zeros afterwards as needed:

   ```
   set last_two=!file_name:~-2,2!
   rem The following line removes all leading zeros:
   for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("!last_two!") do set last_two=%%Z
   set /A last_two+=0 & rem this avoids `last_two` to be empty if it is `0`
   set /A add_millisec=last_two+1
   set add_millisec=0!add_millisec!
   set add_millisec=!add_millisec:~-2!
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   set last_two=!file_name:~-2,2!
   rem The following two lines remove all leading zeros:
   cmd /C exit !last_two!
   set /A last_two=!ErrorLevel!
   set /A add_millisec=last_two+1
   set add_millisec=0!add_millisec!
   set add_millisec=!add_millisec:~-2!
   ```

   This method is more flexible as you do not know the number of digits.